# How to store double using SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, variables, memory, double, store

I am having trouble storing a double in the phone's memory. What are my other options if this isn't possible. Basically what the code is aiming to do using sharedpreferences is take the stored value of "Alcohol" spending and then add whatever the input is in the editText to it and then store that new value for the next time. *Running total of spending on alcohol*

**Can someone please help with this issue and be detailed where x y & z should go in the project.

The user selects from a spinner, which works.

public void addInput(){

```
    double dblCostInput = Double.valueOf(inputBox.getText().toString());
    String strCategories= spinnerCategories.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(strCategories.equals("Alcohol"))
    {

        alcoholSpend = alcoholSpend + dblCostInput;
        inputBox.setText("");
        nextInput();
        inputBox.setText("Your Spending on"+strCategories+" is: " +d.format(alcoholSpend));

    }
```

Comment: If you're doing any money related tasks in doubles, you're going to have a bad time as doubles are not precise values. Consider treating money values as integers (i.e., storing 100x values rather than doubles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putString("double", "0.28").commit();
```

and then to retrieve the double, simply use Double.parseDouble:

```
Double.parseDouble(getSharedPreferences("MY_PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getString("double", "0.28"));
```

Comment: where do i put my double name and value?

Comment: what is the 0.28 then? and "double" is the name of my variable?

Comment: Consider using apply() instead commit() - commit writes its data to persistent storage immediately, whereas apply will handle it in the background

Answer (score 2):

Try below code for setting/putting & getting double with sharedpreferences :

```
 ////////////////////////////////////Setter/////////////////////////

Editor putDouble(final Editor edit, final String key, final double value) {
  return edit.putLong(key, Double.doubleToRawLongBits(value));
}

//////////////////////////////Getter//////////////////////////////

double getDouble(final SharedPreferences prefs, final String key, final double defaultValue) {
return Double.longBitsToDouble(prefs.getLong(key,   Double.doubleToLongBits(defaultValue)));
}
```

Comment: I just get an error that says void method cannoth return value? Also where would i insert my double in the above part? Value?

Comment: @user3924167 you haven't tried my answer. Everything has been mentioned clearly & there is no void stuffs